# does this regex mean what i think it means?

Tags: regex

**Regex:**

```
start\_[a-z0-9]{3,}\_[a-z0-9]{3,}\.txt
```

**what i think it means:**

1. match on any string that begins with "start_"
2. then has alphanumeric
   substring greater than 3 characters
3. then separated with an
   underscore
4. then has alphanumeric substring greater than 3
   characters
5. finally has a ".txt" extension

**question:**

can anyone confirm this behavior? I am able to verify pretty much everything via good except for what "{3,}" means. Any help is greatly appreciated!

-tsnm

Comment: `{3,}` means "at least 3", not "greater than 3". Otherwise, yes.

Comment: thanks! if you make that an official answer, i'll give you the credit.

Comment: Note that (at least in any regex dialect I know) `_` is not a special character and does not need to be escaped. So `\_` could just be written as `_`.

Comment: a valid point sepp2k. Thanks! i didnt even realize that until now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're very close. Let's take this in turn, as you did:

### `start\_`

> match on any string that begins with "start_"

Correct.

### `[a-z0-9]{3,}`

> then has alphanumeric substring greater than 3 characters

Close. It means "has alphanumeric substring 3 characters or more".

### `\_`

> then separated with an underscore

Correct.

### `[a-z0-9]{3,}`

> then has alphanumeric substring greater than 3 characters

Again, close. It means "has alphanumeric substring 3 characters or more".

### `\.txt`

> finally has a ".txt" extension

Correct.

Comment: it says i can accept the answer in ten minutes. Thanks again for breaking it down for me.

Answer (score 10):

A few comments -

1. `start\_` should be `^start\_`. That way you are assured its the
   start of the string (and not potentially the middle)
2. `[a-z0-9]{3,}` is any *lowercase* alphanumeric character. If you want uppercase also you should make it `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. Also if you want it to be greater than 3 (and not equal to) make it `{4,}`
3. This is good
4. Same problems as 2
5. If you want to make sure the .txt is at the end you should make it `\.txt$`.

Without my suggestions, this would match -

`blahblahlbahstart_abc123_abc123.txtblahblahblah`

And this would not -

`start_ABC123_ABC123.txt`

Also, '`_`' is not a special character for regexes. This means it should *not* be escaped by a `\`. So your final regex should be -

`^start_[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,}_[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,}\.txt$`

Answer (score 3):

I would say that you are close, but not entirely correct.

```
[a-z0-9]{3,}
```

will match *3 or more* lower-case letters or digits.  If your regex is run in a case-insensitive text it will also match upper-case letters.

As written, your regex will match any string that contains the pattern.  If you wanted it to match the entire string, you would use markers for the beginning and end of the string:

```
^start\_[a-z0-9]{3,}\_[a-z0-9]{3,}\.txt$
```

Also, you probably don't need to escape the underscore.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very usefull tool
https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/rext/

That way you can test it yourself. If programming in weblanguages, you would have to refresh every change, this updates on the fly, so you can tweak your regex very fast :)

Answer (score -2):

start_ then 3 alphanumeric character and then _ then allow 3 alphanumeric character followed by the .txt formate file name

Comment: Sorta right but you are missing a bunch of stuff... Also its 3 or more, not just 3